# Need help choosing a toroid to wind an inductor for a high-pass filter

Tags: rf, filter, inductor, passive-filter, high-pass-filter

Trying to listen to HF but my RTL-SDR V3 is being overloaded by AM broadcasts so I'd like to build a high-pass filter to block the AM broadcast band. I thought I'd start simple and try making the one shown in Fig 3 of ["Dealing with AM Broadcast Band Interference to Your Receiver"](https://www.dxing.com/tnotes/tnote06.pdf):

[image: schematic]

Concerning the inductors...  The document talks about using T50-2 or T50-15 but I only have T37-2 and T37-6 on hand. I can use https://toroids.info to figure out how many turns I'd need on the T37s to make 3.3 uH, but is there any particular reason to choose one or the other of the T37s I have? The fact that the author of the document seems fine with T50-2 *or* T50-15 makes me think that the "optimum resonant circuit range" of the toroid isn't very important in this application.

Does this filter design resonate on lower frequencies, meaning it would be better to use the T37-2 which has an optimal range of 250 kHz to 10 MHz?

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Define interface impedances SVP.

Comment: define desired attenuation at 1 MHz and antenna impedance

Comment: You also need to define the passband like 30 MHz to ? GHz

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The specific question is in the title: Which toroid should I use? The details in the question specify that I have T37-2 and T37-6 on hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too early to ask because first you must define any filter with specs for;

- input and output impedance (could be 75 or 50 ohms)
- Band reject f and -dB min
- Bandpass f start stop.
- once you define the specs above you can realize it as I have done with parasitics ~ 0.8nH/mm +/-25% for short paths depending on trace geometric l/w.
- Then choose SMD parts suitable for the upper BW range you need and layout on same board in a very tight space.
- There will already be series LC parts on board between RF in and 50 ohm antenna port. Just replace them as required.
- The 75 ohm was just the antenna or preamp, not to be added .
- for better performance use an antenna preamp with filtered DC instead of ground from the 200 nH shunt.
- The board will also have back-to-back diodes for lightning noise limiters.

I made some assumptions  but you may tune any part with mouse wheel or right mouse to edit here in [Falstad's afilter web sim.](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%2016905175966.395636%0Ar%20948%20419%20948%20531%200%2075%0Ag%20948%20531%20948%20547%200%0A170%20820%20419%20788%20419%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AO%20948%20419%20996%20419%200%0Ar%20820%20419%20884%20419%200%2075%0Al%20884%20307%20884%20419%200%202.0000000000000002e-7%20-0.6670847110793358%0Ag%20884%20307%20868%20307%200%0Ac%20884%20419%20932%20419%200%201.5e-10%200%0Al%20932%20419%20948%20419%200%205e-9%20-0.010791244163668997%0Ax%20916%20332%201419%20335%202%2016%205%20nH%20is%20just%20parasitic%20ESL%20for%2010mm%20est.%20path%20incl%20cap.%20(keep%20very%20short)%0Ax%20771%20287%201409%20290%202%2016%20200%20nH%20is%20not%20critical%20and%20may%20be%20larger%20and%20could%20be%20DC%20power%20for%20a%20pre-amp%20on%20antenna.%0Ax%201042%20383%201274%20386%202%2016%20Rough%20BPF%20for%2020%20MHz%20to%206%20GHz%0A)

[image]

Comment: I see now the radio Rin = 50 Ohms

Comment: Thanks for responding but my question isn't about what filter to build. As stated in the question, I've already decided to build the filter recommended in the linked article and I am assuming that the author of that article took all these factors into account and my question is about which of the toroids I have on hand should be used to make the inductors.

Comment: In the question I wrote that I am "trying to listen to HF", so about 3 to 30 MHz. The filter presented in my question is supposed to have a cutoff frequency somewhere between 1.7 and 3.0 MHz, according to the linked article that it comes from.